# Templog file size auto increase daily in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server database generated a temp log file and I am frustrated because this file daily takes near about 10-12 GB space so I have to daily shrink the log file.

What can I do to solve this? Can I set it to auto-shrink ? Or any update in the query?

Comment: How often are you doing log backups? It seems that there is also some kind of process that consistently needs that much space in the logs, so shrinking the log files is likely detrimental to your instance. ~12GB is nothing in storage space, why are you bothered by it?

Comment: The transaction log grows because *the queries require it*, not because of some SQL Server bug or configuration. Transaction logs record every transaction and are used to recover aborted transactions. If you get 12 GB of log entries every day, it's because some script makes all those modifications. Perhaps, there's code that truncates a huge fact or report table and reloads it?

Comment: @Larnu 12GB of data isn't a lot, but 12 GB of new daily transaction log data is certainly weird

Comment: @Larnu, Yes,  12 GB is nothing but I have 100 Gb and If its take daily 10-12 gb then within some day my system fall down. and also daily shrink is issue because  if I forget to shrink then it very troubled  for me ?  do I able to understand my issue ? do you have any solution ?

Comment: So you are saying your logs are actually getting 12GB larger everyday, rather than it grows to 12GB, and then your shrink and it gets back to 12GB the next day? So after 10 days you have a 120GB log file? This sounds like you aren't doing regular log backups. You haven't answered the question on how regular those are.

Comment: @Larnu temp log file is .ldf file and i have not need to backup it.

Comment: What do you mean by a "temp log". Do you mean `tempdb`'s log file?

Comment: @Larnu Yes, exactly !!

Comment: So, *if* the log file of `tempdb` grew to 120GB, that means that *some process* ***needed*** 120GB in the log, @Dharmishtha .

Comment: @Larnu Yes, you are right but on the daily bases How can I shrink daily it ?  and may be its not a professional way. IF you have any solution please help me solve this.

Comment: You would better off finding out what the process you have is that *needs* 120GB space in the `tempdb` log file, @Dharmishtha . It's all well and good setting up a shrink every day, but if that process is just going to run again after you've shrunk it, then the instance growing that file is going to be expensive, and it's just going to be at 120GB again; you aren't *really* saying any storage space.

Comment: last favour form your side .How can I check which process or Which thing taking space ?

Comment: Are you using Simple or Full Recovery mode? If the latter, how often are you backing up? If you are not backing up then set to Simple recovery. See also https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29829/why-does-the-transaction-log-keep-growing-or-run-out-of-space

Comment: @Charlieface, We are using Simple Recovery mode.

Comment: I suggest you look at why it's expanding: what processes are you running? Is something doing a big bulk insert, or perhaps a batch delete job, or an index rebuild, or maybe just leaving a transaction open for a long time. It might be an application or a SQL Server Agent job, or a scheduled task/cron.

Comment: @Charlieface  I am using job for data sync from other server to my server. in this process my job bring lords of data in bulk of form where once I called 10,000 record....so this is my process  in this process what can I do ?

Comment: Don't run it all in one transaction maybe? Are you using Bulk Copy or `bcp`?

Comment: @Charlieface my steps -> 1-> Bring data from other server to  my temp table.
2->  now From temp table to my server using pagination . and drop temp table.